# Difference between is_user_logged_in and $_session['uname']

Tags: users, conditional-tags

I am writing a condition to check if a user is logged in, not sure which of the below condition to use :

```
 if(!is_user_logged_in()){
```

And

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
```

Basically need to check if any user is logged in.

Comment: If you need to check if a user is logged in, use `is_user_logged_in()` function. I think it is quite self-explanatory. $_SESSION['uname'] is a variable and like any other variable, it can be unset, set, changed, ..... The function `is_user_logged_in()` actually checks if the current user exists, not only if he/che has a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core function for checking whether a user is logged in is [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://ex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in). You should use that if at all possible.

WordPress does not use sessions at all, by default, and never has so far as I can remember. When I try `var_dump($_SESSION);` I get an "Undefined variable" Notice exactly as I expected. I haven't explicitly tested with the latest release but I doubt it introduced such a radical change.

If your site uses sessions, it is not the Core doing it. There must be a plugin involved. If that plugin uses sessions as a part of a custom login system you may have to use `$_SESSION['uname']` but hopefully your plugin is written such that `is_user_logged_in()`, [which is pluggable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), works correctly with the custom login system.

Comment: THanks man . Seems the session was being created by some custom code.